# Illuminate\Broadcasting\BroadcastException: auth_key should be a valid app key laravel 5.8

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, pusher, laravel-echo

I am integration laravel pusher it is working fine on local host but on live server in queue it is giving this error

```
Illuminate\Broadcasting\BroadcastException: auth_key should be a valid app key
```

env file

```
BROADCAST_DRIVER=pusher
PUSHER_APP_ID=*****
PUSHER_APP_KEY=****
PUSHER_APP_SECRET=*****
PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER=ap2
```

broadcating.php

```
  'pusher' => [
            'driver' => 'pusher',
            'key' => env('PUSHER_APP_KEY'),
            'secret' => env('PUSHER_APP_SECRET'),
            'app_id' => env('PUSHER_APP_ID'),
            'options' => [
                'cluster' => 'ap2',
                'useTLS' => true,
            ],
        ],
```

Comment: The error indicates an issue with the app key. 
Have you verified there are additional characters/whitespace around the app_key?
Have you cleared the cache and restarted?

Answer (score 0):

I got this error because I put all keys in config/broadcasting.php file instead of .env file.
so do not use broadcasting directly.

some time in broadcasting file we put env('PUSHER_APP_KEY'), but we have PUSHER_KEY in env file. so carefully match .env with broadcasting